# Installing JasperServer 6.3.0 on CentOs 7 ISSUE

Tags: mysql, jasperserver

Try installing JasperServer 6.3.0 on CentOs 7, when I execute ./js-install-ce.sh 
I got this message error:

**BUILD FAILED**

> /opt/jasperreports-server-cp-5.6.0-bin/buildomatic/bin/validation.xml:494:
>   The following error occurred while executing this line:
>   /opt/jasperreports-server-cp-5.6.0-bin/buildomatic/bin/validation.xml:375:
>   The following error occurred while executing this line:
>   /opt/jasperreports-server-cp-5.6.0-bin/buildomatic/conf_source/db/mysql/db.xml:65:
>   The following error occurred while executing this line:
>   /opt/jasperreports-server-cp-5.6.0-bin/buildomatic/bin/validation.xml:433:
>   The following error occurred while executing this line:
>   /opt/jasperreports-server-cp-5.6.0-bin/buildomatic/bin/validation.xml:469:
>   ***Database doesn't exist. Treating problem with JDBC connection as unrecoverable***

Please if you have any suggestion will be appreciated.

Regards

Comment: You should check script and config files (*xml* files)  to check what DB is expected to be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed by my own, the solution was configuring a user on MySQL with all privileges and open port 3306 on the server